# How to pause after on_event_end in Motion

Tags: raspberry-pi, configuration-files, motion

I would like to include a mandatory pause of 10 minutes between the end of an event and the start of the next one in Motion, but I'm not really sure how to do it.
I've seen it's possible to pause it via web control, but I would like to pause it after the end of an event in the configuration file. And then start it again 10 minutes later.

Thank you for your help!

https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#on_event_end

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bash script and link it to the `on_event_end` trigger in your config.

The script could pause the motion detection via webcontrol (use localhost only with a password!) and enable it again after X seconds of sleep.

```
curl -kL -u user:password https://localhost:{port}/{camid}/detection/pause
sleep 60
curl -kL -u user:password https://localhost:{port}/{camid}/detection/start
```

Look at this section of the docs for more info about the webcontrol commands: https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#OptDetail_Webcontrol